# External paths not linking to each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

This is going to sound like a pointless question, but I decided to try out GitHub pages and put something up so that it can go into a portfolio one day. However, all of a sudden the JavaScript isn't linking. I've used the same method I've always used. I thought how about I create a folder to put the HTML, CSS, & JS into but nothing. The css connects just fine. Keep in mind I am using Visual Studio Code for this project.

```js
document.getElementById("ft1").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var feet = document.getElementById("ft1");
  var meters = document.getElementById("m1");
  var result9 = feet.value / 3.2808;
  meters.value = result9;
});
document.getElementById("ft2").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var feet1 = document.getElementById("ft2");
  var inch = document.getElementById("inch1");
  var result10 = feet1.value * 12;
  inch.value = result10;
});
document.getElementById("ft3").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var feet2 = document.getElementById("ft3");
  var cm = document.getElementById("cm1");
  var result11 = feet2.value / 0.032808;
  cm.value = result11;
});
document.getElementById("ft4").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var feet3 = document.getElementById("ft4");
  var yard = document.getElementById("yard1");
  var result12 = feet3.value * 0.33333;
  yard.value = result12;
});
document.getElementById("ft5").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var feet4 = document.getElementById("ft5");
  var km = document.getElementById("km1");
  var result13 = feet4.value / 3280.8;
  km.value = result13;
});
document.getElementById("ft6").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var feet5 = document.getElementById("ft6");
  var miles = document.getElementById("miles1");
  var result14 = feet5.value * 0.00018939;
  miles.value = result14;
});
document.getElementById("meter1").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var m1 = document.getElementById("meter1");
  var feet = document.getElementById("output1");
  var result15 = m1.value * 3.2808;
  feet.value = result15;
});
document.getElementById("meter2").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var m2 = document.getElementById("meter2");
  var inches = document.getElementById("output2");
  var result16 = m2.value * 39.370;
  inches.value = result16;
});
document.getElementById("meter3").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var m3 = document.getElementById("meter3");
  var cm = document.getElementById("output3");
  var result17 = m3.value / 0.01;
  cm.value = result17;
});
document.getElementById("meter4").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var m4 = document.getElementById("meter4");
  var yards = document.getElementById("output4");
  var result18 = m4.value * 1.0936;
  yards.value = result18;
});
document.getElementById("meter5").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var m5 = document.getElementById("meter5");
  var km = document.getElementById("output5");
  var result19 = km.value / 1000;
  km.value = result19;
});
document.getElementById("meter6").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var m6 = document.getElementById("meter6");
  var miles = document.getElementById("output6");
  var result20 = m6.value * 0.00062137;
  miles.value = result20;
});
document.getElementById("inches1").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var inch1 = document.getElementById("inches1");
  var feet01 = document.getElementById("output7");
  var result21 = inch1.value * 0.083333;
  feet01.value = result21;
});
document.getElementById("inches2").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var inch2 = document.getElementById("inches2");
  var meters02 = document.getElementById("output8");
  var result22 = inch2.value / 39.370;
  meters02.value = result22;
});
document.getElementById("inches3").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var inch3 = document.getElementById("inches3");
  var cm03 = document.getElementById("output9");
  var result23 = inch3.value / 0.39370;
  cm03.value = result23;
});
document.getElementById("inches4").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var inch4 = document.getElementById("inches4");
  var yards04 = document.getElementById("output10");
  var result24 = inch4.value * 0.027778;
  yards04.value = result24;
});
document.getElementById("inches5").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var inch5 = document.getElementById("inches5");
  var km05 = document.getElementById("output11");
  var result25 = inch5.value / 39370;
  km05.value = result25;
});
document.getElementById("inches6").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var inch6 = document.getElementById("inches6");
  var mile06 = document.getElementById("output12");
  var result26 = inch6.value * 0.000015783;
  mile06.value = result26;
});
document.getElementById("centi1").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var cm11 = document.getElementById("centi1");
  var feet11 = document.getElementById("ans1");
  var result27 = cm11.value * 0.032808;
  feet11.value = result27;
});
document.getElementById("centi2").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var cm22 = document.getElementById("centi2");
  var meters11 = document.getElementById("ans2");
  var result28 = cm22.value / 100;
  meters11.value = result28;
});
document.getElementById("centi3").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var cm33 = document.getElementById("centi3");
  var inches11 = document.getElementById("ans3");
  var result29 = cm33.value * 0.39370;
  inches11.value = result29;
});
document.getElementById("centi4").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var cm44 = document.getElementById("centi4");
  var yards11 = document.getElementById("ans4");
  var result30 = cm44.value * 0.010936;
  yards11.value = result30;
});
document.getElementById("centi5").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var cm55 = document.getElementById("centi5");
  var km11 = document.getElementById("ans5");
  var result31 = cm55.value / 100000;
  km11.value = result31;
});
document.getElementById("centi6").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var cm66 = document.getElementById("centi6");
  var miles11 = document.getElementById("ans6");
  var result32 = cm66.value * 0.0000062137;
  miles11.value = result32;
});
document.getElementById("yards1").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var yard1 = document.getElementById("yards1");
  var fty = document.getElementById("op1");
  var result33 = yard1.value * 3;
  fty.value = result33;
});
document.getElementById("yards2").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var yard2 = document.getElementById("yards2");
  var ytm = document.getElementById("op2");
  var result34 = yard2.value / 1.0936;
  ytm.value = result34;
});
document.getElementById("yards3").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var yard3 = document.getElementById("yards3");
  var yti = document.getElementById("op3");
  var result35 = yard3.value * 36;
  yti.value = result35;
});
document.getElementById("yards4").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var yard4 = document.getElementById("yards4");
  var ytc = document.getElementById("op4");
  var result36 = yard4.value / 0.010936;
  ytc.value = result36;
});
document.getElementById("yards5").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var yard5 = document.getElementById("yards5");
  var ytk = document.getElementById("op5");
  var result37 = yard5.value / 1093.6;
  ytk.value = result37;
});
document.getElementById("yards6").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var yard6 = document.getElementById("yards6");
  var ytmi = document.getElementById("op6");
  var result38 = yard6.value * 0.00056818;
  ytmi.value = result38;
});
document.getElementById("kilometer1").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var kilom1 = document.getElementById("kilometer1");
  var kmtf = document.getElementById("kmtf");
  var result39 = kilom1.value * 3280.8;
  kmtf.value = result39;
});
document.getElementById("kilometer2").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var kilom2 = document.getElementById("kilometer2");
  var kmtm = document.getElementById("kmtm");
  var result40 = kilom2.value * 1000;
  kmtm.value = result40;
});
document.getElementById("kilometer3").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var kilom3 = document.getElementById("kilometer3");
  var kmti = document.getElementById("kmti");
  var result41 = kilom3.value * 39370;
  kmti.value = result41;
});
document.getElementById("kilometer4").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var kilom4 = document.getElementById("kilometer4");
  var kmtc = document.getElementById("kmtc");
  var result42 = kilom4.value * 100000;
  kmtc.value = result42;
});
document.getElementById("kilometer5").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var kilom5 = document.getElementById("kilometer5");
  var kmty = document.getElementById("kmty");
  var result43 = kilom5.value * 1093.6;
  kmty.value = result43;
});
document.getElementById("kilometer6").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var kilom6 = document.getElementById("kilometer6");
  var kmtmi = document.getElementById("kmtmi");
  var result44 = kilom6.value * 0.62137;
  kmtmi.value = result44;
});
document.getElementById("miles01").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var miles111 = document.getElementById("miles01");
  var feet111 = document.getElementById("milestft1");
  var result45 = miles111.value * 5280;
  feet111.value = result45;
});
document.getElementById("miles02").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var miles222 = document.getElementById("miles02");
  var meters222 = document.getElementById("milestmt2");
  var result46 = miles222.value / 0.00062137;
  meters222.value = result46;
});
document.getElementById("miles03").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var miles333 = document.getElementById("milesti3");
  var inches333 = document.getElementById("milesti3");
  var result47 = miles333.value * 63360;
  inches333.value = result47;
});
document.getElementById("miles04").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var miles444 = document.getElementById("miles04");
  var cm444 = document.getElementById("milestcm4");
  var result48 = miles444.value / 0.0000062137;
  cm444.value = result48;
});
document.getElementById("miles05").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var miles555 = document.getElementById("miles05");
  var yards555 = document.getElementById("milesty5");
  var result49 = miles555.value * 1760;
  yards555.value = result49;
});
document.getElementById("miles06").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var miles006 = document.getElementById("miles06");
  var km006 = document.getElementById("milestkm6");
  var result50 = miles006.value / 0.62137;
  km006.value = result50;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #1b283b, #1d2440, #261f42, #321641, #3f073a);
  margin: 0;
  color: #85929e;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}
.arithmetics {
  height: 600px;
  width: 850px;

}
.numbers {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 210px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #85929e;
  color: #85929e;
}
.btns {
  background: none;
  color: #85929e;
  border: 2px solid #85929e;
}
.conversions {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}
.lists, li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Length Converter</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="converterstyle.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="converterscript.js"></script>
</head>
  <ul class="lists">
    <li>
  <div class="conversions">
    <h2>Feet Conversion</h2>
    <input type="number" id="ft1" class="numbers"><label>feet to meters</label><input type="number" id="m1" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="ft2" class="numbers"><label>feet to inches</label><input type="number" id="inch1" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="ft3" class="numbers"><label>feet to cm</label><input type="number" id="cm1" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="ft4" class="numbers"><label>feet to yards</label><input type="number" id="yard1" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="ft5" class="numbers"><label>feet to km</label><input type="number" id="km1" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="ft6" class="numbers"><label>feet to miles</label><input type="number" id="miles1" class="numbers">
  </div>
    </li>
    <li>
  <div class="conversions">
    <h2>Meter Conversions</h2>
    <input type="number" id="meter1" class="numbers"><label>meters to feet</label><input type="number" id="output1" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="meter2" class="numbers"><label>meters to inches</label><input type="number" id="output2" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="meter3" class="numbers"><label>meters to cm</label><input type="number" id="output3" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="meter4" class="numbers"><label>meters to yards</label><input type="number" id="output4" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="meter5" class="numbers"><label>meters to km</label><input type="number" id="output5" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="meter6" class="numbers"><label>meters to miles</label><input type="number" id="output6" class="numbers">
  </div>
    </li>
    <li>
  <div class="two">
  <div class="conversions">
    <h2>Inch Conversions</h2>
    <input type="number" id="inches1" class="numbers"><label>inches to feet</label><input type="number" id="output7" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="inches2" class="numbers"><label>inches to meters</label><input type="number" id="output8" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="inches3" class="numbers"><label>inches to cm</label><input type="number" id="output9" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="inches4" class="numbers"><label>inches to yards</label><input type="number" id="output10" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="inches5" class="numbers"><label>inches to km</label><input type="number" id="output11" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="inches6" class="numbers"><label>inches to miles</label><input type="number" id="output12" class="numbers">
  </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
  <ul class="lists">
    <li>
  <div class="conversions">
    <h2>CM Conversions</h2>
    <input type="number" id="centi1" class="numbers"><label>cm to feet</label><input type="number" id="ans1" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="centi2" class="numbers"><label>cm to meters</label><input type="number" id="ans2" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="centi3" class="numbers"><label>cm to inches</label><input type="number" id="ans3" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="centi4" class="numbers"><label>cm to yards</label><input type="number" id="ans4" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="centi5" class="numbers"><label>cm to km</label><input type="number" id="ans5" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="centi6" class="numbers"><label>cm to miles</label><input type="number" id="ans6" class="numbers">
  </div>
    </li>
    <li>
  <div class="conversions">
    <h2>Yard Conversions</h2>
    <input type="number" id="yards1" class="numbers"><label>yards to feet</label><input type="number" id="op1" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="yards2" class="numbers"><label>yards to meters</label><input type="number" id="op2" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="yards3" class="numbers"><label>yards to inches</label><input type="number" id="op3" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="yards4" class="numbers"><label>yards to cm</label><input type="number" id="op4" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="yards5" class="numbers"><label>yards to km</label><input type="number" id="op5" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="yards6" class="numbers"><label>yards to miles</label><input type="number" id="op6" class="numbers">
  </div>
    </li>
    <li>
  <div class="conversions">
    <h2>KM Conversions</h2>
    <input type="number" id="kilometer1" class="numbers"><label>km to feet</label><input type="number" id="kmtf" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="kilometer2" class="numbers"><label>km to meters</label><input type="number" id="kmtm" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="kilometer3" class="numbers"><label>km to inches</label><input type="number" id="kmti" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="kilometer4" class="numbers"><label>km to cm</label><input type="number" id="kmtc" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="kilometer5" class="numbers"><label>km to yards</label><input type="number" id="kmty" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="kilometer6" class="numbers"><label>km to miles</label><input type="number" id="kmtmi" class="numbers">
  </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="lists">
    <li>
  <div class="conversions">
    <h2>Mile Conversions</h2>
    <input type="number" id="miles01" class="numbers"><label>miles to feet</label><input type="number" id="milestft1" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="miles02" class="numbers"><label>miles to meters</label><input type="number" id="milestmt2" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="miles03" class="numbers"><label>miles to inches</label><input type="number" id="milesti3" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="miles04" class="numbers"><label>miles to cm</label><input type="number" id="milestcm4" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="miles05" class="numbers"><label>miles to yards</label><input type="number" id="milesty5" class="numbers">
     <input type="number" id="miles06" class="numbers"><label>miles to km</label><input type="number" id="milestkm6" class="numbers">
  </div>
    </li>
    <li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obviously the snippet works, but when I open the project in a web browser (Firefox in my case) it doesn't run the JS.

Comment: Go on the dev tools, and see what's the error...

Comment: There is no dev tools option when I go to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked for the path of the JS file? Maybe you move it and didn't update the path. It'll work on the snippet because everything is in the same place. Maybe post a link to the Github project, we could see the tree of your project.